# Change Keyboard Mapping

Tags: layout, windows-8, keyboard, mapping, shortcut

Hello and thank you in advance,

I am wondering if there is a way to change the layout of my keyboard (software-wise).
The problem is that, on my laptop's keyboard, the Page Up and Page Down keys are combined with the Home and End keys respectively (i.e. to use Home, I have to use the command fn+PgUp/Home).
Is there a way for me to switch what my keyboard receives in Windows 8? If I press the PgUp/Home key I would like the Home command to be entered, and if I entered fn+PgUp/Home I would like the PgUp command to be entered.

I have tried googling for this using several different keywords, but haven't been able to find anything.

Any help is appreciated,
Zach

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question.

You can find an answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/694465/remapping-a-keyboard-key-in-windows-8-1

Keep in mind this does require registry edits which can be dangerous and can lead to critical failures if not done correctly. Always create a restore point before making any registry edits.